# Excel: convert seconds to dd Days hh:mm:ss format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to convert seconds into dd *days* hh:mm:ss.

This is what I have:
I have a cell (A1) with value 457003 and in Cell B1 I am doing =Text(A1/(24*60*60),"dd hh:mm:ss" and it is returning 05 06:56:43.

What i am looking for is 05 ***days*** 06:56:43.

Please help!!

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=TEXT(A1/(24*60*60),"dd \d\a\y\s hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]

Though I would simply use the formula part and do a custom format of `dd \d\a\y\s hh:mm:ss`.  That way the number can be used in later calculations.

Comment: Thank you that helped!! But how would I go about converting days into hours? So in this case it will be 126:56:43 instead of 5 days 06:56:43

Comment: new question = new post but `[hh]:mm:ss`

Comment: Thank you again!! I know it should have been a new question but stackoverflow only allows 1 question per 90 mins. Anyways thank you for your help!!